# Writing elements to a file as they are dequeued from the queue : Scala fs2 Stream

Tags: scala, io, queue, fs2

I have a small test of fs2 streams, process elements, waiting and then write them to a file.
I'm getting a type error saying and I could not figure out what it does mean:

Error : `required: fs2.Stream[[x]cats.effect.IO[x],Unit] => fs2.Stream[[+A]cats.effect.IO[A],Unit],
found   : [F[_]]fs2.Pipe[F,Byte,Unit]`
    import java.nio.file.Paths

```
import cats.effect.{Blocker, ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Timer}
import fs2.Stream
import fs2.io
import fs2.concurrent.Queue

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

class StreamTypeIntToDouble(q: Queue[IO, Int])(implicit timer: Timer[IO]) {
  import core.Processing._

  val blocker: Blocker =
    Blocker.liftExecutionContext(
      scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    )
  def storeInQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {

    Stream(1, 2, 3)
      .covary[IO]
      .evalTap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pushing $n to Queue")))
      .metered(Random.between(1, 20).seconds)
      .through(q.enqueue)

  }
  def getFromQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    q.dequeue
      .evalMap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pulling from queue $n")))
      .through(
        io.file
          .writeAll(Paths.get("file.txt"), blocker)
      )

  }
}

object Five extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val program = for {
      q <- Queue.bounded[IO, Int](10)
      b = new StreamTypeIntToDouble(q)
      _ <- b.storeInQueue.compile.drain.start
      _ <- b.getFromQueue.compile.drain
    } yield ()
    program.as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, and the first is the most confusing. `writeAll` is polymorphic in its context `F[_]`, but it requires a `ContextShift` instance for `F` (as well as `Sync`). You don't currently have a `ContextShift[IO]` in scope, so the compiler won't infer that the `F` for `writeAll` should be `IO`. If you add something like this:

```
implicit val ioContextShift: ContextShift[IO] =
  IO.contextShift(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)
```

…then the compiler will infer `IO` as you'd expect.

My suggestion for cases like this is to skip the type inference. Writing it out with the type parameter is only marginally more verbose:

```
  .through(
    io.file
      .writeAll[IO](Paths.get("file.txt"), blocker)
  )
```

…and it means that you'll get useful error messages for things like missing type class instances.

Once you've fixed that issue there are a couple of others. The next is that using `evalMap` in this context means that you'll have a stream of `()` values. If you change it to `evalTap`, the logging side effects will still happen appropriately, but you won't lose the actual values of the stream you call it on.

The last issue is that `writeAll` requires a stream of bytes, while you've given it a stream of `Int`s. How you want to deal with that discrepancy depends on the intended semantics, but for the sake of example something like `.map(_.toByte)` would make it compile.

Comment: thank you for these clarifications. in regards to the last issue, what If I have a String instead of Int or maybe a type that I have created such as Event.. The toByte conversion would work I think , will it ?

Comment: For a string you'll want `getBytes`, which is from the Java API. You might want to provide a charset explicitly, since if you call `s.getBytes()` with no argument you'll get the platform's default charset.

Comment: what about an explicit type of my creation such as Event, Operation or simply Person ?

Comment: For some other type that you've defined yourself, you'll need to specify how you want it to be serialized into bytes. There are lots of libraries that can help with this (like Scodec, or Circe if you can use JSON). You could also use Java serialization, which lets you avoid additional dependencies, but has many unpleasant aspects IMO and doesn't match the philosophy of Scala libraries like fs2.